# jquery compare datetimes from SQL Server table with a datetime from user and get the date from table

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql

How can I compare two dates? I have two question...

First date I have from table:LastDate (datetime)- 2016-08-31  01:07:00.000

but when I checked ,I get wrong date:

`console.log((new Date(Date.parse((item.LastDate),"MM/dd/yyyy  hh:mm:ssa"))));`

I get - Date 2016-01-09T14:16:00.000Z , how can I get here right date?

Second date - it's today date today.getdate()

How can I compare between them?

I try :

```
if(item.LastDate>=today.getdate()){('#div').show();}
else{('#div').hide();}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use momentjs library: http://momentjs.com
It is very handy, you can do like this:

```
if( moment(item.LastDate, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.ssss").isSameOrAfter(today.getdate()) ){
    ('#div').show();
} else {
    ('#div').hide();
}
```

I'm assuming here that today.getdate() is returning a javascript Date object.